# Java - StackOverflowError for prime recursion

Tags: java, recursion, stack-overflow

Why does this code give me a stackoverflowerror? I'm trying to make the count primes function faster than `O(n**2)`.

**My Code:**

```
public class TestingJavaCode {

    public int countPrimes(int n) {
        int counter = 0;
        n--;

        if (n > -1 && this.isPrime(n)) {
            counter++;
        }

        counter += countPrimes(n);

        return counter;
    }


    public boolean isPrime(int n) {
        for (int i = 2; i < n; i++) {
            if (n % i == 0)
                return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: you decrement n but when does the recursion stop? At the moment the recursive call is always hit

Comment: Just a sidenote: you can skip almost half of your iterations since every even number, except 2, can't be a prime

Answer (score 0):

There is an error in the code that makes the recursion endless.

But even if this was not the case, in total you create `n` stack frames for `countPrimes`. Make `n` large enough and you will get a stack overflow.

In this case you can easily use a loop instead of the recursion. This will also run slightly faster.

A much more effective speedup is possible in `isPrime`, you actually just need to check divisors up to the square root of the number. And after checking 2 you also don't need to check other even divisors.